# display an image from web using IPython.display.image: sometimes work, sometimes not

Tags: python, html, image, jupyter-notebook

---

**This has been solved. As pointed by James in the comment, the link that does not work is not a direct link to an image.**

---

I'm learning python through a ipython notebook online. In the ipython notebook, an image from web is displayed using IPython.display.image. I tried it on my laptop and it works. However, when I try to display other images from web, it does not work.

The scripts that work is:

```
from IPython.display import Image
url = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Kosaciec_szczecinkowaty_Iris_setosa.jpg'
Image(url,width=300, height=300)
```

The scripts that do not work (but show a broken image without any other outputs) is:

```
from IPython.display import Image                        
url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_setosa#/media/File:Kosaciec_szczecinkowaty_Iris_setosa.jpg'
Image(url,width=300, height=300)
```

I saw two other related questions but they still do not answer my questions.

[Display an image from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23173980/display-an-image-from-uri)

[How to display an image from web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962180/how-to-display-an-image-from-web)

Thank you very much!

Comment: The second URL is not a direct link to the image URL, but rather displays a webpage with a wrapper around the image.

Comment: @James, thank you so much! Now I understand. I should click the image in the link I provided to get the direct link to the image URL. Then it works!

Comment: No problem.  If you ever have trouble getting the image URL, you can always right-click on the image and copy the image location or inspect the element to find where the URL was called from.

Answer (score 9):

First you have to get image.
simply you can do it using requests

```py
import requests
import IPython.display as Disp
url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Kosaciec_szczecinkowaty_Iris_setosa.jpg'
Disp.Image(requests.get(url).content)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is now available without requests in IPython using `url` keyword:

```py
from IPython import Image

Image(url="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Kosaciec_szczecinkowaty_Iris_setosa.jpg")
```

Comment: I think you mean `from IPython.display import Image`